# Is every space a classifying space?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, classifying-spaces

Despite a pretty thorough look (I think) I can’t find the answer to the following question: Is every (reasonable?) path connected space weakly equivalent to the classifying space of some topological group?

I’ve found some related results, such as the Kan-Thurston theorem, but nothing that answers this question.

Comment: This is true. If X is a pointed, path-connected space, then its loop space $\Omega X$ is weakly equivalent to a topological group and $X$ itself is weakly equivalent to its classifying space. This is perhaps most easily proven by working with simplicial sets, see Goerss-Jardine V.5 and V.6.

Comment: To expand on what Piotr said, there is an equivalence of categories between so-called 'grouplike E_1-spaces' and pointed connected spaces.  It is then a classical theorem that every grouplike E_1-space admits a strict model (due to Stasheff I think? Although he would have called an E_1 space an A_∞-space).

Comment: @PiotrPstrągowski Might as well post your excellent (and highly-upvoted) comment as an answer.